# Why am I not able to route to another page?

Tags: reactjs

I am a react learner. First time doing a login page. I have created a login page with google-login, successfully able to logging in to a page with sign-out button. From there I want to traverse other pages, it shows a warning and not launching to that page.

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a `useEffect` cleanup function.

For that I have created a reusable header component inside that imported my google-login component and using it. So only first launch everything asper but when routing from there to any other page giving me the above error.

I have not used `useEffect`anywhere:

1. Google login page
2. Login page with google-login button
3. Header component with google-login.

How can I come out from this.

##### `login.js`:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './login.css';
import { Link,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import GoogleLogin from '../login/GoogleLogin.jsx';

function Login(props) {
  return (
    <div className="login__container">
        <GoogleLogin className="g-signin" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

##### `header.js`

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import GoogleLogin from '../login/GoogleLogin.jsx';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import './Header.css'
import { Link,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function Header() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const handleMoreInfo = () => {
        history.push("/contacts");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center">
                <Link to="/contacts">Contacts</Link>
                <div class="navbar-collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
                        <GoogleLogin />
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" onClick={handleMoreInfo}>More Info</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

##### `GoogleLogin.js`:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleLogin, GoogleLogout } from 'react-google-login'; 
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const clientId = "Your client ID";

function Googlelogin(props) {
    const [showloginButton, setShowloginButton] = useState(true);
    const [showlogoutButton, setShowlogoutButton] = useState(false);
    const history = useHistory(); 
    const onLoginSuccess = (res) => {
        console.log('Login Success:', res.profileObj);
        setShowloginButton(false);
        setShowlogoutButton(true); 
        history.push("/pagination");
    };

    const onLoginFailure = (res) => {
        console.log('Login Failed:', res);
    };

    const onSignoutSuccess = () => {
        alert("You have been logged out successfully");
        history.push("/");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            { showloginButton ?
                <GoogleLogin
                    clientId={clientId}
                    buttonText="Sign In"
                    onSuccess={onLoginSuccess}
                    onFailure={onLoginFailure}
                    cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
                    isSignedIn={true}
                /> : null }

            { showlogoutButton ?
                <GoogleLogout
                    clientId={clientId}
                    buttonText="Sign Out"
                    onLogoutSuccess={onSignoutSuccess}
                ></GoogleLogout> : null }
        </div>
    );
}

export default Googlelogin;
```

Comment: Please share code , so that we can answer better

Comment: @GouthamJ.M will do

Comment: @GouthamJ.M i have edited ,Hope this is ok

Comment: Yeah I will have a look at it

Comment: `setShowloginButton(false);` `setShowlogoutButton(true); ` 

you could group these into one you don't need 2 state variables here you could just check if one is true and in the other case if its false

Comment: @ahmedcheikhsidahmed that I have corrected  thank you, still my problem persist

Comment: Why don't you try instead of using the useHistory hook conditionally rendering a Redirect jsx element based on state

Comment: @ahmedcheikhsidahmed I have tried this in header
 let [isLoggedIn,setIsloggedIn]= useState(false);
  const handleMoreInfo = () =>{ 
      
      if(localStorage.getItem('Name')!=" ")
      setIsloggedIn(true);
        if(isLoggedIn)
        return  <Redirect to='/contacts' />
    }
its not working still ,is this correct?

Comment: try putting this in your `return()` `{isLoggedIn && <Redirect to="/contacts" />}`